# How to create migration for CASCADE constraint?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do i create a migrations to add a CASCADE constraint?

this is my code

```
 'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((t) => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.addConstraint("cars", "user_id", {
          // onDelete: "CASCADE",
          allowNull: false
        }, {
          transaction: t
        })
      ])
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((t) => {
      // return Promise.all([

      // ])
  })
  }
};
```

I dont know how to add a constrain to a existing foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do so by drop the constraint and then recreate it with raw query of alter table. something like below:

```
var table = 'YOURTABLENAME';
var constraint = 'YOURCONSTRAINTNAME';
var constraintFkey = 'CONSTRAINTFKEY';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${table}" drop constraint "${constraint}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${table}"
          add constraint "${constraint}" foreign key("${constraintFkey}") references "users" ("user_id")
          on delete cascade`
      ));
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`alter table "${tableName}" drop constraint "${constraintName}"`)
      .then(() => queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `alter table "${tableName}"\
          add constraint "${constraintName}" foreign key("${constraintFkey}") references "users" ("user_id")
          on delete no action`
      ));
  },
};
```